# Multi-column check constraints

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a "movies" table and I need to add a constraint to the effect that "Steven Spielberg" movies must be before 1990 and "James Cameron" movies must be after 1990.

I am new to Oracle SQL. I tried some queries but they did not work. Something like

```
alter table movie_16bce1346 add constraint chk_spk 
                if director='Steven Spielberg' then check (year>1990);
```

What's the right way to write this constraint?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Just as a manner of policy, I would not make a rule like this a constraint. I would create a separate table of these constraints, and enforce it with  either update/insert procedures or an update/insert trigger. This would provide much more flexibility as additional movies are added, and/or as the constraints require modification.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint should be something like this:

```
( director not in ('Steven Spielberg', 'James Cameron') or
  director is null   /*  if that is allowed  */         or
  director = 'Steven Spielberg' and movie_year < 1990   or
  director = 'James Cameron'    and movie_year > 1990       )
```

You could use parentheses around the AND-separated conditions in lines 3 and 4, if you don't trust your developers to be very familiar and comfortable with the precedence of AND and OR.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use a CASE statement](http://www.databasestar.com/oracle-case-statement/) within a CHECK constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE movie_16bce1346 
ADD CONSTRAINT check_year CHECK
  (CASE
    WHEN director = 'Steven Spielberg' AND movie_year > 1990 THEN 1 
    WHEN director = 'James Cameron' AND movie_year < 1990 THEN 1
    WHEN director NOT IN ('Steven Spielberg', 'James Cameron') THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END = 1);
```

The CASE captures your conditions, which need to return a 1 or 0. The "END = 1" says that the result of the CASE needs to equal 1.

Comment: This will reject any movie with director *other than* Spielberg or Cameron.